# Extend LineString on map zoom

Tags: linestring, zoom

In OpenLayers 5, I have some LineString that represent the streets. Now I want that when the map is zoomed also the LineString should be zooomed.

For example in the following image, I have two linestrings at zoom level 1. At zoom level 2 near the blue lane, this should be zoomed and the red lane should be horizontally scrollable. How can I do this?

[image]